Google AdvertisingID of devices that updated my app from the Google Play Store
I know that some users download my app (organically or via ads) but for some reasons they don't open it. My goal is to increase the number of users who open the app after they download it (for example with target ads).
Question: assuming apps are updated overnight in background by the Google Play Store even if they've never been opened, is it possible to invoke the Google Play Store API to have the list of devices (Google AdvertisingID) that have updated the app?
Thank you

It is possible, but it may not be completely reliable or quick.
If your app has permission to receive events, then you could use the start of those BroadcastReceiver events to trigger a service to start that could retrieve the data that you are asking about.
With this approach, you would just need to have another metric, like a call from your MAIN activity to sort out how many apps are installed vs. launched.
I will refrain from posting anything related to BroadcastReceivers, Services and the Google API's work, since there are lots of ways to do this. As an example, you could get the BOOT_COMPLETED intent, and then after a device reboot, you would send this data. The TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED intent would happen often if you have READ_PHONE_STATE permission.
Notice that these are repetitive events, so you would want to record that you sent the data somewhere, so it is only sent once. Maybe have a flag in SharedPrefs to track it and the AdvertiserID that was sent.
Be careful to not do this for a permission that needs to be granted at runtime, as apps that have not launched will not have that permission, and fail.
Good luck!
